# Regex to remove all whitescape except one between words?

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

Simple as the title, really.

Is there a Regex expression to remove all whitespace except one between words.

So

```
"  Hello. How   are  you     today?    "
```

would become

```
"Hello. How are you today?"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This will do what you wish:

```
"  Hello. How   are  you     today?    ".replace(/\s{2,}/g,' ').trim()
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/REAdV/

Comment: One suggestion: Use `\s{2,}` to avoid unnecessarily replacing single spaces with themselves.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! :) I saved this to my Jsfiddle for any future people to have a look at, as your link is just to the main site. :) http://jsfiddle.net/MythOfEchelon/Qkm7a/

Comment: @BenHooper - In your fiddle, there is no `onInput`... it should be `onChange`.

Comment: How'd you mean? I'm aware that `onInput` is not supported in IE8 or lower, if that's what you mean. I use it because it covers copy and pasting, whereas `onChange` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

As you may find that `trim()` may not work fro ie 6/7/8 and some older browsers versions I would suggest using `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'')`

```
var str = "    fsdf d34234sf    sdfsdf   "; 
str=str.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
returns:fsdf d34234sf sdfsdf
```

Comment: No it doesn't, this only removes leading and trailing whitespace, not the space in between words. This comes closer: `str.replaceAll('^\s+|\s{2,}|\s+$')`. Of course this answer was 8 years ago so trim() is fine to use nowadays...